# Assigning value to variable within multiple while loops

Tags: java, json, variables, while-loop, scope

I have a block of code that is searching through a JSON file in order to find a match, once it finds a match it assigns an associated value from the JSON file to the variable `currentLocation`. The question I am asking is how to assign this value to `currentLocation` and access it outside of the while loop?

Code block:

```
String currentLocation = null;
try {
  JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("src/resources/objectLocation.json"));
  jsonReader.beginObject();
  while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
    String nameRoot = jsonReader.nextName();
    if (nameRoot.equals("locations")) {
      jsonReader.beginObject();
      while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
        String name = jsonReader.nextName();
          jsonReader.beginObject();
          while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            String n = jsonReader.nextName();
            n = jsonReader.nextString();
            if (n.equals(currentObject)) {
              currentLocation = name;
            }
          }
          jsonReader.endObject();
      }
      jsonReader.endObject();
    }
  }
  jsonReader.endObject();
  jsonReader.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
return currentLocation + " " + currentObject;
```

From my understanding what is happening is that the value I am looking is being assigned to `currentLocation` OK but it then falls out of  scope where I am trying to access it thus returning null.

I have tried declaring it as:

```
final String currentLocation;
```

Which is then giving me the error `variable currentLocation might be assigned in a loop` which of course it is.

How can I access the value of `currentLocation` as it is within the while loop in my return statment?

Comment: Why not replace `currentLocation = name` with `return name+" "+currentObject` (move `jsonReader.close()` to the `finally` block)?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that your code might be throwing an exception? Hence you get the currentLocation as null?

Comment: I've assigned a fake value to `currentLocation` and it is successfully returned.

Comment: @TagirValeev if I do that my code is complaining about a missing `return` after the `catch` block. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @Colin747, just return something appropriate when your parsing fails or nothing found (probably null?). If you think that such situation will never occur, just put `throw new InternalError();` on the last line.

Comment: @Codester apologies you are correct, I didn't realise I'd left the `catch` blank and it is indeed throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be throwing an exception, please check your catch block. If there is no exception it should return the updated currentLocation value.